# Microsoft.Speech.Recognition recognize dictation

Tags: c#, .net, speech

I`m using Microssoft.Speech.Recognition to recognize some speech. I have SDK v11 installed and it works pretty good until I try to AppendDictation to GrammarBuilder:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));

sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
gb.Append("start");
gb.AppendDictation();
gb.Append("end");
Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
sre.LoadGrammar(g);
```

And it crashes at line `sre.LoadGrammar(g)`.

**FileNotFound exception**

Error text:
Cannot find grammar referenced by this grammar.

Am i doing something wrong? I will be grateful for Your help!

Comment: I added full code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the server version of Microsoft's Speech SDK doesn't support dictation grammars at the moment. You should try using the `System.Speech.Recognition` namespace instead of the `Microsoft.Speech.Recognition` namespace. You will need to have speech recognition installed on your server if it is not already installed.